# Max with of Colorbox window?

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I am using an iFrame Colorbox (http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) and I need to make it "responsive".
Right now I have set the width to 90% and it works but after a certain size I do not want it to expand anymore, regardless of screen size. I want to set the max width to 1200px.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried the maxWidth property?  You use it in conjunction with the width property in order to set a max size.  Example: `$('a.example').colorbox({width:'90%', maxWidth:1200});`

Comment: This works great.I removed width:'90%', because there are few small images to show.They get enlarged if I use it.

Comment: @Jack, I'm trying to use this and the maxWidth just seems to get ignored. It's an iframe within the modal, so not sure if that makes a difference? Have you seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

I just did something like this... below is for iPhone/Android. Needs some tweaking depending on content but it's a start for ya'll.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
#colorbox, #cboxWrapper, #cboxContent { width:320px !important; }
}
```